# Emacs auto-complete mode doesn't run automaticlly in rust-mode

Tags: emacs, autocomplete

My `init.el` file has several configs of `auto-complete`:

```
(require 'auto-complete)
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(global-auto-complete-mode t)
;; some codes
(require 'rust-mode)
```

it works on all other modes like `go-mode`, `swift-mode`, elpy, or `cider-mode`. After I open specifically code file, I can see `AC` in mode line.

I just install `rust-mode` this morning, and AC does not start automaticlly when I open .rs file (rust code file).

What I have known now:

1. `global-auto-complete-mode` is `t`.
2. `rust-mode` has been in `ac-modes` value.
3. I can start `auto-complete` manually.

I can add hook to `rust-mode` to run `auto-complete`. However, I'd like to know why it does not work well. Is there any other value I missed? Or `rust-mode` turn off AC?

Answer (score 0):

Add `rust-mode` to `ac-modes`.

```
(add-to-list 'ac-modes 'rust-mode)
```

Also, consider reporting a bug to the [auto-complete](https://github.com/auto-complete/auto-complete) project so it's enabled by default.

Comment: Thank you jpkotta. `rust-mode` already in `ac-modes`, I think I need send issue to `rust-mode`